# failed to load /usr/bin/dotnet: exec format error

Tags: c#, .net, docker, digital-ocean-apps

I'm trying to use DigitalOcean to host a [C# docker container](https://hub.docker.com/layers/181428399/alyxw/alace-cs/latest/images/sha256-1266857b8efa54bff28f11a25d3c9464b95fa58640a91880716f88bff616b087?context=repo) on docker hub (With the Apps platform)

`[2021-12-08 23:24:04] starting container: starting non-root container [dotnet Alace.cs.dll]: creating process: failed to load /usr/bin/dotnet: exec format error`

The container runs perfectly fine on my computer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your image is built for an Arm processor and the DigitalOcean machine is probably an amd64 machine.

You can try building for amd64 with the buildx command. Something like

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t alyxw/alace-cs:amd64 .
```

Comment: It’s strange OP can run that thing on their computer. Maybe they use an apple computer with M1 CPU?

Comment: Lots of people have M1 Macbooks, so it not that strange :)

Comment: Yes, I am on an m1, thank you so much!

Comment: @Alyx Consider using ARM64 CPUs on the cloud too. I have once made a cloud app in .NET Core running on a public cloud, in my case ARM VMs which I ended up using were 2.5x cheaper than a traditional AMD64 VMs. Another nice side effect, you won’t need another version of these docker images. However, single-threaded performance is better on traditional Xeons and Epics, so that’s a trade-off.

Comment: @Soonts do you know if DigitalOcean supports ARM64? I have a bunch of credit with them so I'm determined to make that work

Comment: When you make a droplet, the only CPU options are Intel or AMD as far as I can see

Comment: @Alyx I’m afraid it does not. Among the large cloud provides, arm64/Linux VMs are available on Amazon and Oracle.