# ASP.NET Docker image exits immediately in AWS ECS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a dockerized ASP.NET application that I am hosting on AWS ECS. I have a task definition with one container image: the ASP.NET app, which is marked as essential. When I run that task in a service, the task provisions, is running, and then immediately changes to `DEPROVISIONING (Essential container in task exited)`. I can run the image on my machine (with Docker Desktop) with no problem, the image listens on the specified port and doesn't exit, as expected. The issue seems to be that when I run that container on ECS, the container immediately exits.

Here is my Dockerfile, I don't see anything wrong, but I could be mistaken.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /App

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /App
COPY --from=build-env /App/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webapi.dll"]
```

Comment: What does the ccontainer log say?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue after looking at the logs like [Hans Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) was wondering.

The error I was getting was "exec /usr/bin/dotnet: exec format error". After reading [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283385/failed-to-load-usr-bin-dotnet-exec-format-error), I discovered that the platform I was building for was specific to my machine, an m1 mac. In order to run my container on AWS Fargate, I had to build for linux amd64, using this command: `docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t {app-name}:latest`.